# Table extraction using Adobe

Tags: python, pdf, adobe

Good day,

I am using the Adobe api with python to extract only the tables and their bounding boxes. I am using the following code:

```
    #Create an ExecutionContext using credentials and create a new operation instance.

    execution_context = ExecutionContext.create(credentials)

    extract_pdf_operation = ExtractPDFOperation.create_new()


    #Set operation input from a source file.

    source = FileRef.create_from_local_file(input_pdf)

    extract_pdf_operation.set_input(source)


    #Build ExtractPDF options and set them into the operation

    extract_pdf_options: ExtractPDFOptions = ExtractPDFOptions.builder().with_element_to_extract(ExtractElementType.TABLES).build()

    extract_pdf_operation.set_options(extract_pdf_options)


    #Execute the operation.

    result: FileRef = extract_pdf_operation.execute(execution_context)


    #Save the result to the specified location.
    zip_file ="tem_tables.zip"
    result.save_as(zip_file)
```

What I want is not to save them as a excel file, but somehow to have a list of all tables structure with their bounding boxes as excel. So variable with the excel data in it, not to save it

Comment: In the ZIP file, you should see a "structuredData.json" file. This will have references to the tables as well as their bounding boxes. Search the JSON for "Table" and you'll see them.